# How do I get the UUID of a partition and define a Bash variable as being equal to it?

Tags: bash, partition, uuid

I would like to define a Bash variable `PART_ID` as being equal to the UUID of the `/dev/sdb1` partition. The closest I have gotten to the desired answer is the output of:

```
ls -ld /dev/disk/by-uuid/* | grep sdb1
```

which, for me, gives:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Mar 16 17:02 /dev/disk/by-uuid/d26c3e60-0cfb-4118-9dec-1f1819439790 -> ../../sdb1
```

which is not an acceptable value for me to set `PART_ID` to. Rather what `PART_ID` should equal is `d26c3e60-0cfb-4118-9dec-1f1819439790`.

Comment: This has been asked before, seach... `my_uuid=$(lsblk /dev/sdb1 -no UUID)`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Note that's the UUID of the filesystem (or other structured data with a UUID the udev scripts know about) on the partition, not the UUID of the partition itself (not all partitioning schemes give UUIDs to partition anyway). See also [Difference between UUID from blkid and mdadm?](/a/129499).

A few options on Linux-based systems to get the FS UUID:

```
fs_uuid=$(blkid -o value -s UUID /dev/sdb1)
fs_uuid=$(lsblk -no UUID /dev/sdb1)
fs_uuid=$(udevadm info -n sdb1 -q property | sed -n 's/^ID_FS_UUID=//p')
fs_uuid=$(find /dev/disk/by-uuid -lname '*/sdb1' -printf %f)
```

The first one may require superuser privileges or at least the right to read the device.

If the filesystem is mounted, you can also use:

```
fs_uuid=$(findmnt -fn -o UUID /dev/sdb1)
```

Comment: Just a follow-up.  other than `udevadm` and `find` commands, superuser privilege is required for **`blkid`, `lsblk`, and `findmnt`** command.

Comment: `fs_uuid=$(lsblk -ndo UUID /dev/sdb1)` (with the additional `-d` flag) may be more effective if /dev/sdb1 has descendants, as can be the case if used in a RAID, LVM, or as an encrypted partition.

Comment: If you're using busybox then `blkid -o value -s UUID /dev/sdb1` won't work. It seems to ignore all flags. So if you're on alpine install blkid via `apk add blkid`, and then run the command.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it in this way

`PART_ID=$(blkid -o value -s UUID /dev/sdb1)`

Answer (score 0):

Putting it all together (thank you, @Mongrel!):

This will automagically get the

```
DISK=$(mount | grep " $1 type" | awk '{print $1}')
PART_UUID=$(blkid -o value -s UUID ${DISK})
echo "DISK UUID ($1): ${PART_UUID}"
```

Output:

```
DISK UUID (/): cf9eb16f-c1fa-45d1-9764-b10f064cc993
```